# this.jq.draggable is not a function using any Primefaces component

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use the dialog component like in:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/loginDemo.xhtml

But it doesn't work and browser's console is showing the error below:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.jq.draggable is not a function

Comment: Did you manually include jQuery or jQuery UI in your web application?

Comment: @BalusC, yes, I included this line: <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />

Comment: That's the PrimeFaces one (which is normally already auto-included). So you mean to say that you didn't manually include your own copy of jQuery?

Comment: I'm also using bootstap framework. 
<script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/scripts.js"></script>

Comment: As I guessed. Get rid of it. One jQuery is enough.

Comment: Just read the answer in the duplicate question?